# Prove that $((7+\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}+ (7-\sqrt{48})^{2k+1})\times \frac{1}{2}\equiv 3 \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to prove that $((7+\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}+ (7-\sqrt{48})^{2k+1})\times \frac{1}{2}\equiv 3 \pmod4$ for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
I’ve tried to do it by induction but it didnt work… or at least I can’t do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If those numbers are $a_k$, show that they satisfy $a_{k+2}-194a_{k+1}+a_k=0$. Show that $a_0$ and $a_1$ satisfy $a_n\equiv3\pmod{4}$. Then since $194\equiv2\pmod{4}$, you can inductively prove it.

Comment: In general, sequences $x_n=C_1r_1^n+C_2r_2^n$ satisfy a recurrence of the form $x_{n+2}-(r_1+r_2)x_{n+1}+r_1r_2x_n=0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{48}=4\sqrt3,$ so it seems as easy as looking in the ring $R/4R,$ where $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt3].$ Maybe it needs $R/8 R.$

Comment: Binomial expand. Odd terms cancel, even terms after first have factor of 48 leaving $7^{2k+1}$.

Comment: **Hint:** $\bmod 8\!:\ (7\!\pm\! \sqrt{48})^2\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,2N\equiv 7\!+\!\sqrt{48}+(7\!-\!\sqrt{48})\equiv 6,\,$ so $\,N \equiv 3\pmod{\!4}\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

The difference equation approach to this problem would be:

$7 + \sqrt{48}$ and $7 - \sqrt{48}$ are roots to the polynomial equation
$$x^2 - 14 x + 1 = 0$$

Thus the solutions to the recursion $a_{n+2} = 14 a_{n+1} - a_n$ are of the form $C_1 (7 + \sqrt{48})^n + C_2 (7 - \sqrt{48})^n$. We want $C_1 = C_2 = {1 \over 2}$ here, which correspond to $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 7$. Modulo $4$ these are
$a_0 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $a_1 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$.

Using the recursion $a_{n+2} \equiv 14 a_{n+1} - a_n \equiv 2 a_{n+1} - a_n \pmod 4$, one then sees that $a_n$ alternates between $1$ and $-1$ modulo $4$. thus the odd terms are all going to be $-1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ as needed.

Answer (score 1):

From the binomial $(7\pm\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}$ equal to
$$7^{2k+1}\pm\binom{2k+1}{1}7^{2k}\sqrt{48}+\binom{2k+1}{2}7^{2k-1}\sqrt{(48)^2}\pm\binom{2k+1}{3}7^{2k-2}\sqrt{(48)^3}+\cdots\pm(48)^{2k+1}$$ we get
$$\frac{(7+\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}+(7-\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}}{2}=7^{2k+1}+48M$$ where $M$ is an integer. It follows, because of $7^{2k+1}\equiv3^{2k+1}=9^k\cdot3\equiv1\cdot3\pmod4$ and because $48M\equiv0\pmod4$ that
$$\frac{(7+\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}+(7-\sqrt{48})^{2k+1}}{2}\equiv3\pmod4$$
We are done.